# Snowflake Reference Table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to create a reference table in Snowflake that picks up the column name and the column value together as a result to be referenced in another SQL Query ?

Suppose on I have an Item Table ( as shown below - )

| ITEM_NAME|ORDER_TYPE | REGION|

|:--------|:----------:|------:|

|  Godan | Return| North|

And I have a set of rules as mentioned below

- If Item name is '%NAME% then YES
- IF Region is 'NORTH' then NO etc

What would be the best possible way to create a reference table in Snowflake containing the results of these rules which can be later accessed by any other view in Snowflake(Column and Value together) or and ETL Tool ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any particular area you got stuck?

Comment: You'll definitely have to explain more about what you are trying to do here (or what problem you are trying to solve). It's not at all clear what you are looking for from this one sentence.